# How to pipe a propane kitchen correctly

Tags: plumbing, gas, propane

Just purchased a new house and found a great surprise, a 500-gallon propane tank buried in the backyard. Not sure how old it is, but it is holding gas, a gas contractor came out and checked and it still has gas. The previous owner was using it for the pool heater, but they switched to electrical, now it is unused.

We want to install a gas cooktop, we are remodeling our kitchen and our GC and the same gas contractor said that we should run a line from the cooktop to the outside of the house and said we could use copper. So my GC installed [this 1/2 inch type L flexible copper](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Everbilt-1-2-in-x-20-ft-Type-L-Soft-Copper-Coil-Tubing-1-2-L-20RE/203654563) from the cooktop area to the wall outside, (*in the floor*) wrapped it in a 1" electrical PVC pipe so it has long 90" elbows, and installed new tile on top.

We called a plumber this morning and he came out and said that we should have used a rigid pipe, and that he will not go near the flexible pipe. He also suggested that instead of running a line from the existing tank, to just had a new 100 gallon tank and place it near the kitchen wall and use a flare connector to hook it up.

Any recommendations on what I should do here?

Do i need redo the floor? Please say nooo

[image: Text]

Comment: Can you add some photos, etc? It is hard to understand _"...from the cooktop area to the wall outside, (in the floor) wrapped it in a 1" electrical PVC pipe..."_   And what is _"possible buried line"_? You should, as the plumber suggests be using a rigid gas pipe, or flexible pipe designed for gas, rather than electrical conduit...  Apparently the GC was the wrong person to do the plumbing. Have the plumber take care of it then call back the GC to fix the floor, etc. since he screwed it up.

Comment: I'm not at the house now, but to clarify we added a flexible copper line wrapped in PVC from the cooktop area to the outside of the house. The possible buried line would be a polyethylene line to where the cooktop line is

Comment: I thought that general purpose soft copper tubing could not be used to carry natural gas. I'm not sure about propane (LPG). I thought some compounds (e.g., the mercaptan odorants) in the gas reacted with uncoated copper.

Comment: @JimStewart I have seen many propane lamps plumbed with copper on cabin walls . Of coarse there is no code requirements for these cabins.

Comment: Does propane (LPG) used for heating and cooking contain odorant imparting additives or is LPG odorless as it's provided to the end user?

Comment: When the OP writes the copper tubing is wrapped in PVC, I think he must mean the contractor assembled a conduit of Schedule 80 PVC which is used as electrical conduit and has long radius 90 deg elements.

Comment: I think your gas plumber is non-cooperative because he can't inspect the pipe and confirm that any joins were done correctly.  soft copper is the same stuff as hard copper it's just been cooked a bit to soften it.  Type L copper is approved for indoor use for gas, the thicker type K it required underground.  If the pipe run is a single piece of copper it should be fine, but your plumber needs to know that, which probably means he needs to see it.

Comment: I have seen advertisements for a process for coating the inside of copper water pipes with epoxy. This was claimed to be a preventative for pinhole leaks in copper piping used for water supply. The claim was that this could be done to water supply piping in place in a structure.

Comment: https://www.nuflowtech.com/internal-pipe-coating/ Perhaps this process could be used to prevent internal corrosion in copper tubing being used for gas piping. New copper tubing presumably would require little or no cleaning. Was the copper tubing used in this case refrigeration grade soft copper tubing? Of course, LPG may not corrode soft copper like NG does and so internal coating may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that type L  copper tubing is used for LPG / propane "distribution" in the US,  but is not allowed for natural gas. https://findanyanswer.com/what-type-of-copper-tubing-is-used-for-propane-gas.